# Is it possible to keep a variable active with Revit Python Shell, using canned commands?

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell

I'm currently using Revit Python Shell **2017** and I'd like let's say to make "communicate" different canned commands.
For instance, let's say I load a house model, and I create some additional walls on it, via a canned command that I would have previously created. While creating these walls, I could store all these new walls IDs in a variable, as a list.

Now, if I want to delete exactly these walls afterwards, I'd like to identify them using their IDs that I stored in the list, then delete them.
If I was in an interactive Python Shell session, well the "IDs list" variable would still be accessible (as long as I don't close the shell), and I could just retrieve the IDs from it, then delete the walls.
But what if I'm using canned commands? The first command would be "create the walls", and the 2nd would be "erase these walls". But that "IDs list" variable doesn't exists in the second canned command environment, so that I can't use it to erase the walls.

So, what would be the approach? Of course in this example I could identify the walls in the second command using a different methodology, such as asking the user to select them etc etc.. But the idea I'm going for would be the store that list from the first command "somewhere in Revit", and retrieve it when calling the second command.

I could write the list to an external text file, and read the file in the second command... but is there a cleaner way?

I'm sorry for the beginner's language used here, and hope that my question is clear enough! And that somebody can help ;)

Best,
Arnaud.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Post your answer if you did, Id be keen to see how you solved it

Comment: I did.. using another way to do it ;) Thanks again! (and I posted my "answer" below)

Answer (score 2):

So,

Just for leaving a trace, I solved this using pyRevit and its ability to store data in temporary files ([here](https://pyrevit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/scriptanatomy.html), look for "Using Temporary Files").

Comment: Very cool Arnaud, some other great pyRevit utilities on that page too

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question Arnaud, in the past Ive done the following:

Create a text project parameter, and populate it with XML (yes you can have line breaks in a text parameter). This is similar to what Ideate BIM Link does (check the project parameters of any project that has used BIM Link). This is a long-winded method for keeping data persistent between commands.

The second part (saving a walls IDs) is more difficult I think, as I understand it every time you open a project the IDs are reassigned. You could test this to see if its the case?

Another method could involve using an External command that lingers after you have finished selecting walls. Could you go into a little more info about what youre wanting to achieve?

Comment: Thanks! Actually this question came to my mind because I create a lot of walls and curves (via doc.Create.NewModelCurve) in my model. The walls I create are of a particular type, so that I can easily identify them afterwards, and erase them (let's say I filter the newly created walls by their type). But with the curves I create, I can't (or "I don't know how to") use similar filtering approach. So I came to the conclusion that the only way I could re-identify these curves would be by their IDs. But for that I need to store the IDs "somewhere" in between the 2 canned commands.  Thanks!

Comment: @Arnaud A robust approach could be to use an External command. Daren has a great example on his website: [darenatwork.blogspot - External command](http://darenatwork.blogspot.co.nz/2015/06/embedding-webserver-in-autodesk-revit_30.html). Im still a little hazy about exacly the process you need, but could you use an External command to store the IDs (or the actual Curve objects), and erase them after the fact? Alternatively, a model curve has a 'Line' type - could you make a new line type for exclusive use by your canned command? So you could Select them all and delete safely?

Comment: Thanks a lot for all this. I'll try that. I could indeed (I guess) use a custom Line type, but the External Command approach would be more 'universal' probably! I'll let you know how it goes! Thansk again!

Answer (score 0):

A way might be using the [Extensible Storage](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/files/cp4451_tammik_estorage.pdf). Quote from the referenced document:

> *Extensible Storage or estorage is a way of programmatically storing arbitrary, auxiliary data in a document.
> It supports simple data types such as integer, double, string, element id, etc., and complex structures such
> as lists and dictionaries.*
>
> *It can be used to replace the old technique of storing data in shared parameters.*
>
> *Access can be restricted to read-only or invisible to other applications.*

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63861112/extensiblestorage-using-revitpythonshell#answer-63942370) contains a Python snippet.